# unable to find optional library

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an  android/PHP  application and I'm using MySQL database. When I execute the code, I found this problem. I added the library `android_http_client-0.2-sources.jar` , but I still have the same problem.
That's what I received in logcat:

```
warning:unable to findoptional library:android_http_client-0.2-sources.jar
```

This is `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mouna.androidproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
android {
useLibrary 'android_http_client-0.2-sources.jar'
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've just edited your post to remove "tks for help". The politeness expressed by "hope this helps", "thank you" and "hello" is all similarly problematic in technical writing. **Stack Overflow, as a Q&A site, strives to be a technical resource akin to encyclopedias. That writing style that makes it useful as a technical resource precludes pleasantries and formalities.** The reason for removing "thank you" is exactly the same as the reason that "hope this helps" isn't at the bottom of every Wikipedia page. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
...
```

and delete this at the bottom:

```
android {
   useLibrary 'android_http_client-0.2-sources.jar'
}
```